# cloudflare CORS Error Try to upload image

Tags: javascript, html, file, cors, cloudflare

I'm Trying to upload my image to my cloudflare. But I got this CORS Error.

[image]

I think this error means cloudflare server do not allow me to upload my photo.

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const url =
    "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/d9db7da39482b78c6ac50679a81f16f7/images/v1";
  const direct_upload_url =
    "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/d9db7da39482b96srg50679a81f16f7/images/v2/direct_upload";
  const TOKEN = "H14yZzMAKcC0NS557jvExS1PjMqgVumgswEOUZ4h";

  const onChange = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("file", e.target.files[0], file.name);
    for (let value of formData.values()) {
      console.log("val", value);
    }

    try {
      const result = await fetch(url, {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`
        },
        body: formData
      });
      if (result) {
        console.log(result);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <input onChange={onChange} type={"file"} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is a code I used.

Please check my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is on the Cloudflare side and not your code. You need to modify the Cloudflare resource CORS policy to allow requests from your domain.

However i'm [not sure this is possible](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cors-blocking-access-to-cloudflare-api/322605) and you might have to use a [CORS proxy](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/cors-header-proxy/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup CORS for your bucket.

> Currently, you have to use the S3 API PutBucketCors to configure CORS for your bucket.

see https://developers.cloudflare.com/r2/data-access/public-buckets/#configure-cors-for-your-bucket